# Why can't I apply nodal at the ground terminal of this Op amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis

[image]

This question is asked to find the value of \$V_o\$ in terms of \$V_s\$ that i already got so don't want solution for this.

I have one doubt,while applying nodal I applied nodal at the ground terminal (that red line pointing) too that gives me incorrect answer.
that i did't understand **why can't I apply nodal at that point?**

what i understand is if I give that three branch separate ground then that will not be a node anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with performing KCL at the reference node shown in the diagram is that that node only tells part of the story: there is an *implied* current return path to the amplifier that the reference node is not accounting for, and there is current from the output of the amplifier flowing *into* that shown reference node (through the feedback resistor and "beyond").

Comment: Thanks... It seems I need to learn some basics of Opamp.